# Unable to retrieve data from an xml to place in an array

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to retrieve a number of flightids from an xml and place them in an array but I keep getting no data displayed. It doesn't seem to find 'flights' but I am not sure why, is there anything wrong with the code below?

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def response = context.expand( '${SOAP Request#Response}'  )
def parsedxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)


def tests= parsedxml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'b:TestId'}

log.info tests

//Get the rate plan codes
    def testId = { option ->
       def res = option.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'b:TestId'} 
        if (res)  return option.TestId.text()   
       null
    }


    def testIdArray = []
    tests.each { if (testId(it)) testIdArray << testId(it) }
    for (int i = 0; i < testIdArray.size(); i++) {
            log.error "TestIds: " + testIdArray[i] 
    }


log.warn testIdArray.size()
```

Below is the xml:

```xml
<s:Envelope xxx="xxx" xxx="xxx">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">xxx</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <XML1 xmlns="xxx">
             <XML2 xmlns:b="xxx" xmlns:i="xxx">              
                      <XML3>
                         <b:TestId>000000</b:TestId>
                      </XML3>
                      <XML3>
                         <b:TestId>000000</b:TestId>
                      </XML3>                 
          </XML2>
      </XML1>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: 1/ i don't see any `FlightSearchResult` tag close, and the xml is not correct

Comment: Are you looking for inbound flight ids? or outbound flight ids? or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the xml string response to below response variable

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)

def getFlightIds = { type = '' ->
    type ? xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == type }.collect { it.FlightId.text() } : xml.'**'.findAll {it.FlightId.text()}
}

//Get the respective flight ids
//Use the desired one as you have mentioned none
def inFlightIds = getFlightIds('InboundFlightInformation')
def outFlightIds = getFlightIds('OutboundFlightInformation')
def allFlightIds = getFlightIds()


log.info "Inbound flight ids: ${inFlightIds}"
log.info "Outbound flight ids: ${outFlightIds}"
log.info "All flight ids: ${allFlightIds}"
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5181471430017024)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Rao very much

Comment: @BruceyBandit, glad it helped. Appreciate if it can upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

`it.name()` in your case `it` is a  [NodeChild](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html)

so, `it.name()` returns just a name without prefix. it means you should compare it to `FlightId` (without `b:` )

if you want to check a namespace (linked to a prefix) then your lookup must be like this:

```
def flights = parsedxml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'FlightId' && it.namespaceURI()=='xxx' }
```